# 1981 amc concord won't start

Tags: engine, starting

I have a 81 amc concord. I drove it and it died and went to start it again there was nothing. Replace starter battery and starter relay. There is no headlights no buzzer no radio no dome light. Any idea whats the problem?

Comment: Try checking your fuses and the ignition switch

Comment: Check the ground to the battery (both sides). You do not have connectivity to the battery.

Comment: Hey Paulster2. This happen once before. But the starter relay and battery was bad. But I drove it for a month now.

Comment: You have lost connectivity somewhere if you are getting nothing as you described. If you replaced the parts a month ago and it solved the issue, more than likely you only masked the true issue. Moving wires/cables around could have caused it to reconnect, but now it's lost it again. I'd check all of your power cables to see where the lack of continuity is located.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fusible Link that possibly has blown, where the positive battery cable connects to the starter relay, there is a smaller red wire usually has heat shrink on it. replacement fusible link avail at NAPA, Advance auto etc, but could also use a fuse and holder.

[image: http://theamcpages.com/images/electric/alt-wiring-b.JPG]

Comment: Hey Paulster2. This happen once before but the battery and starter was bad.I drove it for a month and it happen again.Thanks for the diagram and advice.

Comment: Can the voltage regulator cause this promblem?

Comment: and where is the regulator located at?